# Mysql : Result of Sub Query with Left join wrong Resultset vs Subquery Result

Tags: mysql

I have written a query to get result with limit then result of query left join to other tables.
I am getting correct result if i query only Sub Query

```
SELECT 
    LE.*
FROM
    legder_expenses LE      
WHERE
    LE.created_by = 437
ORDER BY 
    LE.id DESC
LIMIT 
    0,30
```

**Result**

[image]

But when use above query as sub query and left join them to other tables which may have or may not have data

```
SELECT 
    Legder.id,
    Legder.created
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            LE.*
        FROM
            legder_expenses LE      
        WHERE
            LE.created_by = 437
        ORDER BY 
            LE.id DESC
        LIMIT 
            0,30
    ) Legder
    LEFT JOIN legder_voucher_types LegderVoucherType ON LegderVoucherType.id = Legder.legder_voucher_type_id
    LEFT JOIN legder_types LegderType ON LegderType.id = Legder.legder_type_id
    LEFT JOIN legder_expense_details LegderDetail ON LegderDetail.legder_expense_id = Legder.id
    LEFT JOIN legder_expense_images LegderImage ON LegderImage.legder_expense_id = Legder.id
```

**Result**

[image]

i don't know why these query give different result even i using **Left join**

Comment: Your result #1 shows only 22 rows of 30, so it is difficult to understand does the date value marked in Result #2 is present in it or not.

Comment: Strawberry can you can explain more, i could not understand from link

Comment: Hi Akina, my problem is only for first record, not count of records

Comment: I could not get latest records on top that is created = '2020-02-12'

Answer (score 0):

I just add **order by** at end of query now it works fine.

```
SELECT 
    Legder.id,
    Legder.created
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            LE.*
        FROM
            legder_expenses LE      
        WHERE
            LE.created_by = 437
        ORDER BY 
            LE.id DESC
        LIMIT 
            0,30
    ) Legder
    LEFT JOIN legder_voucher_types LegderVoucherType ON LegderVoucherType.id = Legder.legder_voucher_type_id
    LEFT JOIN legder_types LegderType ON LegderType.id = Legder.legder_type_id
    LEFT JOIN legder_expense_details LegderDetail ON LegderDetail.legder_expense_id = Legder.id
    LEFT JOIN legder_expense_images LegderImage ON LegderImage.legder_expense_id = Legder.id
ORDER BY
    Legder.id DESC
```

Comment: There is no point LEFT JOINing tables from which you select no columns